# Trouble accessing Microsoft Graph calendar API. Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I am setting up a daemon process to access Microsoft Graph by retrieving an access token then making a GET request to the *Calendar[dot]Read* API. So far I can retrieve the access token, but I am having trouble making the GET request. Here is my code so far.

```
//// Running on NODEJS.... 
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;        
// App configuration
const APP_ID = '***************************************';   
const TENNANT = '***************************************';
const APP_SECRET = '***************************************';    
const SCOPES = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';      
const TokenEndpoin = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{${TENNANT}}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
const sendcontent = `client_id=${APP_ID}&scope=${SCOPES}&client_secret=${APP_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials`;
const api_url_readCalender = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/`; 
//// Not sure what api_url_readCalender is suppose to be.

/**
 * Run POST to retrieve token then, 
 * Run GET to retrieve calendar API using token...
 */
POST( TokenEndpoin, sendcontent, (data) => {        
    const token_obj = JSON.parse(data);     

    /// Run GET with token and url for read calender.
    GET( api_url_readCalender, token_obj, (data)=> {
        var ojv = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(ojv);
    });

}); 

/// Post & Get Functions...
function POST(destination, scontent, cb) {          
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(http.readyState, http.status);          
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {            
            var data = http.responseText;
            cb(data);    
        }
    };
    http.open( 'POST', destination, true);      
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.send(scontent);/// scontent is sendcontent passed by parameter.    
}

function GET( destination, token,  cb ) {   
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        /// Print readyState and status
        console.log(http.readyState, http.status );         
        console.log( http.responseText);
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {            
            var data = http.responseText;                        
            cb(data);            
        }
    };
    http.open( 'GET', destination, true );
    ///  Use toke_type and access_token for authentication. 
    http.setRequestHeader('Authorization',  token.token_type+' ' + token.access_token); 
    http.send();
}
```

I am pretty sure my permissions are configured correctly on Microsoft azure portal side. I AM NOT sure what the url for accessing the api is suppose to be. Currently api_url_readCalender value is set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/`. That returns a response.text in GET reading...

```
"{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bfdb54e2-f9ad-4d75-be71-45ae807add5f",
      "date": "2019-10-02T23:16:17"
    }
  }
}"
```

Function GET's http.status is returning 403 Forbidden.

My app is registered. The permissions I have selected is 'Microsoft-Graph > Application Permissions > Calendars.Read'.

I am certain my app configuration details are correct. Except for *SCOPES*, and *api_url_readCalender*. Not sure about *SCOPES* because in a Microsoft tutorial I read said just use *.default*. I am not sure about *api_url_readCalender* because I haven't read any clear documentation on what the API address is suppose to be for my use case once I have the token. I want to be able to retrieve the events in my calendar.

Comment: Hi, did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @mtpbzz no I scrapped the project and chose a different career lol